# Blocking access to a folder through http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hosting

I hope this question is not redundant, but I could not find any answer to the exact question I am asking.

I own a multiple site shared hosting plan on a Linux server.
The hosting plan refers to a domain that we can call www.domain1.com

Every other domain is hosted as a subdir of the main domain. so for example domain2.com will be hosted like: www.domain1.com/domain2.com/

It could be reached using that path or using www.domain2.com directly.
I want to disable the access to domain2.com as subfolder of domain1.com.

I suppose I need to put a .htaccess file in every subfolder of domain1.com which is hosting a website. Am I correct? What do I have to put in the .htaccess file?

thank you in advance,
Max

Answer (score 0):

Put these rules in the htaccess file in domain1's document root (the parent folder):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(domain2\.com|domain3\.com)/ - [L,F]
```

Where the `domain2\.com` etc are the subfolders that you don't want to be able to have direct access.

**However**, if you have rewrite rules in each of those subfolders, then you *do* need to add rules in each of the subfolders:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule - ^ [L,F]
```

The `F` flag will cause the request to return a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Hi there and thank you Jon!
I am going to try it this weekend, sorry for the late reply but I thought I was supposed to receive an email when someone answered and I didn't!

Comment: it's partly working....it works when in the folder I have a static site (I have a few of those), but it gives me an error 500 when I have a wordpress site in the folder